# Как перевести данный код в обычный ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Начал работат с  [данной](https://dev.office.com/fabric#Variants) библиотекой
Использую ES6. Наткнулся на такой компонент:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dropdown, IDropdownOption } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown';
import { DatePicker, DayOfWeek, IDatePickerStrings } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DatePicker';

const DayPickerStrings: IDatePickerStrings = {
  months: [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ],

  shortMonths: [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
  ],

  days: [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
  ],

  shortDays: [
    'S',
    'M',
    'T',
    'W',
    'T',
    'F',
    'S'
  ],

  goToToday: 'Go to today',
  prevMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to previous month',
  nextMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to next month',
  prevYearAriaLabel: 'Go to previous year',
  nextYearAriaLabel: 'Go to next year'
};

export interface IDatePickerBasicExampleState {
  firstDayOfWeek?: DayOfWeek;
}

export class DatePickerBasicExample extends React.Component<any, IDatePickerBasicExampleState> {
  public constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      firstDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Sunday
    };
  }

  public render() {
    let { firstDayOfWeek } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker firstDayOfWeek={ firstDayOfWeek } strings={ DayPickerStrings } placeholder='Select a date...' />
        <Dropdown
          label='Select the first day of the week'
          options={ [
            {
              text: 'Sunday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Sunday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Monday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Monday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Tuesday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Tuesday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Wednesday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Wednesday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Thursday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Thursday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Friday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Friday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Saturday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Saturday]
            }
          ] }
          selectedKey={ DayOfWeek[firstDayOfWeek] }
          onChanged={ this._onDropdownChanged.bind(this) }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  private _onDropdownChanged(option: IDropdownOption) {
    this.setState({
      firstDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek[option.key]
    });
  }
}
```

Увидел слова `interface`, `private`,`public`. Прогугглив, понял,что это-`TypeScript`. Попытался найти какой-нибудь трашпиллер, но в данном случае имеем не просто js, а react. Подскажите пожалуйста как это дело можно перевести в обычный es6?

Comment: просто убери то, чего нет в es6 и все должно заработать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интерфейсы и модификаторы приватности в TypeScript просто декоративны, и проверяются только компилятором.

Для перевода данного кода в ES6 нужно просто убрать то, чего еще нет:

1. interface
2. private, public
3. generic классы
4. Типы переменных и параметров.

В итоге получится что-то вроде:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown';
import { DatePicker, DayOfWeek } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DatePicker';

const DayPickerStrings = {
  months: [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ],

  shortMonths: [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
  ],

  days: [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
  ],

  shortDays: [
    'S',
    'M',
    'T',
    'W',
    'T',
    'F',
    'S'
  ],

  goToToday: 'Go to today',
  prevMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to previous month',
  nextMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to next month',
  prevYearAriaLabel: 'Go to previous year',
  nextYearAriaLabel: 'Go to next year'
};

export class DatePickerBasicExample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      firstDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Sunday
    };
  }

  render() {
    let { firstDayOfWeek } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker firstDayOfWeek={ firstDayOfWeek } strings={ DayPickerStrings } placeholder='Select a date...' />
        <Dropdown
          label='Select the first day of the week'
          options={ [
            {
              text: 'Sunday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Sunday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Monday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Monday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Tuesday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Tuesday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Wednesday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Wednesday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Thursday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Thursday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Friday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Friday]
            },
            {
              text: 'Saturday',
              key: DayOfWeek[DayOfWeek.Saturday]
            }
          ] }
          selectedKey={ DayOfWeek[firstDayOfWeek] }
          onChanged={ this._onDropdownChanged.bind(this) }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  _onDropdownChanged(option) {
    this.setState({
      firstDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek[option.key]
    });
  }
}
```